# Extracting I-Frames from H264 in MPEG-TS in C

Tags: c, h.264

I am experimenting with video and would like to know how I can extract I-frames from H264 contained in MPEG-TS container.
What I want to do is generate preview images out of a video stream.
As the I-frame is supposed to be a complete picture fro which P- and B-Frames derive, is there a possibility to just extract the data of the picture without having to decode it using a codec?

I have already done some work with MPEG-TS container format but I am not that much specialized in codecs.

I am rather in search of information.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: though the I-frame is a whole picture, it's still encoded.. decoding it is a complex task. any reason not to use a codec?

Comment: Just wanted to try to do it myself. Is there some library you would suggest?

Comment: Unless you are a real pro, don't even think about decoding it yourself (check the H264 standard *grin*). `x264` and `ffmpeg` is an option, though I have no idea how to force I-frames only.

Comment: @gekod: Just curious to know what "extracting data of the picture" from the I-frame means to you...

Comment: @puffadder: As an I-frame is a whole picture from which P- and B- frames derive from, I wanted to save I-frames as pictures (JPEG?). What I was trying to do is create previews from the stream and save them as images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert in this domain but I believe the answer to your question is NO.

If you want to save the I-frame as a JPEG image, you still need to "transcode" the video frame i.e. you first need to decode the I-frame using a H264 decoder and then encode it using a JPEG encoder. This is so because the JPEG encoder does not understand a H264 frame, it only accepts uncompressed video frames as input.

As an aside, since the input to the JPEG encoder is an uncompressed frame, you can generate a JPEG image from any type of frame (I/P/B) as it would already be decoded (using reference I frame, if needed) before feeding to the encoder.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted decoding h.264 is complicated.  You could write your own decoder but it is a major effort.  Why not use an existing decoder?

Intel's IPP library has the basic building blocks for a decoder and a sample decoer:

[Code Samples for the Intel® Integrated Performance Primitives](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-code-samples/)

There's libavcodec:

[Using libavformat and libavcodec](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html)

[Revised avcodec_sample.0.4.9.cPP](http://web.me.com/dhoerl/Home/Tech_Blog/Entries/2009/1/22_Revised_avcodec_sample.c.html)

Answer (score 2):

I am not expert in this domain too. But I've played with decoding. Use this gstreamer pipeline to extract preview from video.mp4:

```
gst-launch -v filesrc location=./video.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_00 ! ffdec_h264 ! videorate ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=1/1' ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=image-%05d.jpeg
```

If you want to write some code, replace videorate with appsrc/appsink elements. Write control program to the pipelines (see [example](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-helloworld.html)):

```
filesrc location=./video.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_00 ! ffdec_h264 ! appsink
appsrc ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=1/1' ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=image-%05d.jpeg
```

Buffers without GST_BUFFER_FLAG_DELTA_UNIT flag set is I-frames. You can safely skip many frames and start decoding stream at any I-frame.